# Unreadable memory when I create pointer array in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dynamic, data-structures

I'm new to pointers and dynamic memory. The program is supposed to be an array-based stack.
I need help with an error that occurs when I try to allocate memory to the pointer variable `_pArr` in the .h-file. When I try to create a new array with `new double[]` I get an 'unreadable memory' error message when I debug the code.
In the code down below I have created a new array in the .cpp-file and then copy it to the `_pArr` pointer, but I still get the same error.

```
class CStack{
public: 
    Stack(void);
    ~Stack(void);
    .
    .
    .
private:
    int _capacity=NULL;
    int _size=0;
    double* _pArr;
}



CStack::CStack(void)
{
    if (_capacity == 0){
        _capacity = 10;
    }
    else{
        _capacity = _capacity * 2;
    }
    double* arr;
    arr = new double [_capacity]

    _pArr=arr;

    delete[] arr;
}
```

Why does this error occur and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is `arr` and why are you deleting it in the constructor? Also, is the class name `Stack` or `CStack`?

Comment: What's the point of the `if (_capacity == 0)` test? Since this is a newly-created stack, and the class declaration initializes it to `0`, it will always be `0`.

Comment: Off topic, but don't use `NULL` for `int`.

Comment: Do try and use `std::vector` instead of these C-style fixed-size arrays. You'll have far fewer problems.

Comment: Why can't you directly do `_pArr = new double [_capacity]` and later `delete[] _pArr` in the destructor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what your code is doing in the constructor:

```
// Allocate memory for an array and set arr to point to that array.
double* arr;
arr = new double [_capacity]

// Set _pArr to point to the same array.
_pArr=arr;

// Delete the array that arr and _pArr point to. If you
// deference _pArr after this, bad things will happen.
delete[] arr;
```

So you shouldn't be deleting the array immediately after you allocated it. (There's also a missing semicolon there.) Getting rid of that will likely fix your problem, but then you then need to delete the array in the class's destructor. And if you must use `new[]`/`delete[]`, it would be far easier to do it in a single step, rather than creating a useless temporary variable:

```
CStack::CStack(void)
{
    if (_capacity == 0){
        _capacity = 10;
    }
    else{
        _capacity = _capacity * 2;
    }

    _pArr = new double [_capacity];
}

CStack::~CStack(void)
{
    delete[] _pArr;
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but that code that doubles `_capacity` doesn't do anything useful, as capacity will always be zero when the constructor is called. If you intended for this to expand an existing `CStack`, then you will need to put it in a method, and will need to worry about creating a new array for the stack, copying the contents of the old one into the new, and then deleting the old one.